# Trying to fit an iframe within a computer image

Tags: html, css, background-image

HTML:

```
<div>
<img src="Comp.png" id="comp"><iframe width="700"   
height="526"src="http" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>    
</iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#comp {
display: block;
height:700px;
width: 800px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

iframe {
display: block;
height: 385px;
width: 752px;
padding-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Currently the iframe isnt showing up. previously I had used margin positioning to get it within the computer image, but when the browser window resizes it completely throws everything off. Can anyone offer any input? Help is appreciated. Thanks

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bKPKh/

Comment: This is syntactically incorrect. This simply won't work.

Comment: Looks like its there to me?

Comment: Should have a space after the quotes before the src in the iframe

Comment: Create an example on jsfiddle for instance.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/bKPKh/

Comment: Anyone? Still having trouble with this.

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped the image and the iframe within a div with relative position. Also I have wrapped the iframe in a div with absolute postion and fix it above the image with left and top.
Here is an example of my code :

```
<div class="container">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Et22afT.png" height="200" width="200" />
<div class="frame">
    <iframe src="http://www.bbc.co.uk" height="120" width="181"></iframe>
</div>
```

```
.container {
    position:relative;
}
.frame {
    position:absolute;
    left:9px;
    top:15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Beaa/

Answer (score 0):

OP, have you considered a wrapper with relative positioning, and using absolute positioning on the children?

*Relative* positioning positions it as normal, but shifted by some number of pixels along both axis (and those numbers may be 0). On the other hand *Absolute* positioning takes an element out of the normal positioning entirely (kind of like putting something on a new layer in Photoshop) and positions it relative to the most recent ancestor with anything other than static positioning (which is the default), or the document as a whole if there is none.

Confusing, I know! The point is that the wrapper with `position:relative; top:0px; left:0px;` will work exactly like normal (...mostly), but then you can use absolute positioning to put the child elements wherever you want inside it. You'll need to manually set the `height` and `width` of the wrapper, because the absolute-positioned children are, as I said, on another "layer", so they can't affect anything on the main "layer".

Comment: I've tried this, but it still seems that on browser resize the iframe shifts around. I dont know why its behaving like this.